# Jetpack Compose Optional Arguments: What's the string between the braces {}?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

When working with optional arguments in Compose: What's the value **between** the braces?

"item=" is the key. What is the purpose of the string within the braces?

```
composable("Details?item={item}",
        arguments = listOf(navArgument("item") {
            this.type = NavType.StringType
            defaultValue = "Item not available!"
        })) {
```

Comment: It is the `key` of the argument that you pass in the `navArgument`. The value is picked up from the `navArgument` & forwarded ahead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have it backwards - the name of the query parameter (the `item=` part) could be anything. It could be `lorem_ipsum` or `foobar` or any word - that word isn't used by Navigation at all for figuring out how to parse that argument. The only thing that matters is the structure of your route pattern - that query parameter syntax is how you mark a parameter as an [optional argument](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#optional-args). Just like a web URL, you could navigate to `Details` as well as `Details?item=cat` - both would match your route. A required parameter would be part of the path (i.e., `Details/{item}`).

As explained in the [Navigate with arguments guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nav-with-args):

> Navigation compose also supports passing arguments between composable destinations. In order to do this, you need to **add argument placeholders** to your route, similar to how you [add arguments to a deep link](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#implicit) when using the base navigation library

That `{item}` is the placeholder that indicates that whatever string is in the place of the `{item}` should be parsed and put as an argument with the name `item`. This is how you can call `navBackStackEntry.arguments?.getString("item")` and get that parsed value out of the arguments of the destination.